# Qual a diferença de se declarar uma variável com e sem "@" no Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Qual a diferença entre essas duas possibilidades?

```
//com @
@post = Post.find(params[:id])

//sem @
post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

Normalmente nos controllers é usado com `@`, mas em funções `each` das views normalmente é usado sem o `@`, por exemplo.

Existem diferenças de desempenho?

Comment: É como o Bruno disse as variáveis sem o <code>@</code> só pode ser acessada dentro do escopo em que ele foi criado, no caso se você criar no controller, você não poderá acessar a variável na view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as variáveis que possuem `@` são variáveis de instância no escopo do objeto atual.
as variáveis sem `@` são variáveis locais no escopo do objeto atual.

No caso específico do Rails, as variáveis com `@` utilizada nos controllers são disponibilizadas para serem utilizadas "dentro" das views.

Para o `each` que foi citado segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  <faz alguma coisa com 'post' aqui>
end
```

nesse trecho de código, a variável `post` é local ao escopo do bloco em que ela foi definda, portanto ela só existe dentro do bloco `do |post| ... end`

---

Para entender melhor as diferenças entre os tipos de variáveis, classes e objetos, dê uma olhada nesse link http://aprendaaprogramar.rubyonrails.com.br/index.rb?Chapter=09.

Sobre o `each`, olhe aqui http://aprendaaprogramar.rubyonrails.com.br/index.rb?Chapter=07

Comment: Muito bom o site que tu passou. Eu comecei a aprender Rails sem dominar 100% o Ruby, então algumas coisas passam despercebidas.